# Wireless N PCI Card for pfSense 2.3.1 AP?

Tags: wireless, pfsense, freebsd

Can someone recommend a Wireless N PCI Card (not PCIe) for pfSense 2.3.1 that is based on FreeBSD 10.3?

Comment: Please edit this to include the tags freebsd and pfsense.

Comment: Could you add more details on this topic? What are your needs? What is your budget?

Comment: It's for a home proxy server.

Comment: I want to use it as an access point to filter traffic through.

Answer (score 0):

Such cards are not as popular as mini PCIe cards, so you'd better to go for any PCIe-to-miniPCIe card adapter + any supported mini PCIe card (e.g. Atheros).

Check selected mini PCIe card for compatibility by the following lists:

1. https://www.freebsd.org/releases/10.3R/hardware.html
2. https://github.com/bsdhw/Drivers/blob/master/freebsd/freebsd-10.3.list